# ImageMagick ver-6.7.6 "-virtual-pixel transparent" is not working in my Live Server

Tags: imagemagick, php-5.4

I have stuck in a issue regarding imageMagick command -

"-virtual-pixel transparent" is not working on my Live Server, while the version of imageMagick is 6.7.6
The same command is running on my local server where I am having ImageMagick version 6.6.9, below is my commnad for ImageMagick.

```
/usr/bin/convert  -background transparent -depth 8 -matte -channel RGBA -virtual-pixel transparent -font
 "Arial.ttf" -gravity "west"  -density 300 -depth 8 -quality 100 -fill "rgb(0, 0, 0)"  -pointsize
 100  -kerning 0 -dither None label:@"TextFile.txt"  \( +clone -background "rgb(0, 0, 0)" -shadow 0 
\) -background none -compose DstOver -flatten     -resize "839"x"600"  +antialias  -trim png: "test.png"
```

Comment: Both those versions are ancient - consider upgrading.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, ok fine, but at another server, where I am having ImageMagick version 6.7.7, here the given above command is working fine.